# I'm trying to get this form to wait for an ajax response and update a form value before submitting. Why isn't it working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, forms

You'll see this in the code, but my plan was to replace the "submit" button with a regular button, add an click event that makes a json request, and call submit() on the form in the callback of the json request but it doesn't seem to be working. The POST array is totally empty. Here are the relevant parts of my code.

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="POST" id="postForm">
    //There are some other text fields and stuff here
    <input type="hidden" name="isSelfPost" id="isSelfPost"/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" id="submitButton" />
</form>

<script>
    $("#submitButton").click(function submitform()
    {
        var URL = $("#postURL").val();
        if (URL === '')
        {
            document.write('You need to enter a URL.');
            return false;
        }
        var jsonURL = URL + ".json?jsonp=?";
        $.getJSON(jsonURL, function(results){
            var postData = results[0].data.children[0].data;
            var isSelf = postData.is_self;
            $('#isSelfPost').val(isSelf);
            $("#postForm").submit();
        });
    });
</script>
```

The json is coming from reddit if that matters. The request works fine, it just doesn't seem to want to submit. I don't think it's preemptively submitting or anything because the POST array is completely empty.

Thanks for reading.

Edit: Alright, I figured it out. My only issue was that the "name" attribute of my button was called "submit". So when I called "submit()" I my form, it was interpreted as a reference to the button and not the submit function.

Comment: If it doesn't submit, how do you know that the POST array is empty?

Comment: You may need a `e.preventDefault()` to prevent the page submitting the form before you want it to: `$("#submitButton").click(function submitform(e) { e.preventDefault();...`.

Comment: @Pointy I have print_r($_POST) at the beginning of the php.

Comment: @Andy thank you for your response. I tried that but unfortunately it didn't seem to change anything.

Comment: Well then doesn't that mean that the form *is* being posted?

Comment: @Pointy I see what you're saying. When the page first loads up the print_r prings an empty array. When I click the button to submit the form it doesn't print anything else, not even an empty array. So I was wrong that the POST array is empty. It's not even getting to the point where it would print.